# Should I remove confidential files at the end of a GitHub Action workflow?

Tags: security, github, github-actions

I have some actions where I need to store a secret into a file. This secret is used by another job later, like:

```
env:
  FIREBASE_DISTRIBUTION_KEY: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_FIREBASE_DISTRIBUTION_PROD_KEY }}
run: |
  echo $FIREBASE_DISTRIBUTION_KEY > key.json
  export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=key.json
```

From a security perspective, should I remove at the end of the workflow the `key.json`? Like:

```
- name: Remove credentials
  if: always()
  run: |
    rm key.json
```

I'm thinking about a scenario where the GitHub Actions containers are compromised and someone has access to the files. Or not trusting GitHub that they are deleting the GitHub Action container completely.

Comment: From what I understand from the [official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#about-github-hosted-runners), all uncommitted files will be lost at the end of the job execution. Therefore, you shouldn't need to remove those files manually at the end of your job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not necessary.

First, GitHub Actions runners are not containers, they're virtual machines. There's no opportunity for container escape, and there's no notion of "cleaning up" the containers.

The virtual machine is disposed of completely. Neither the virtual machine that ran your job - nor any of its disk images - will be re-used.